# Can I bulk delete shared media on Android texts?

Tags: delete, media-files

When I go into the texting app and click on the settings, then shared media, it allows me to delete gifs/images individually by clicking on the three dots, but I want to get rid of 90% of these and doing it one by one is a slog.  Any advice?

Comment: May be you should try an app that has been designed to manage files? There are quite a few file manager apps available in Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

I use X-plore app to manage the files. Heres the screenshot of the top of the tree.

[image]